# Magento 2 : Difference among afterMethodName, beforeMethodeName and aroundMethodName?

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin

What are the difference in `afterMethodName`, `beforeMethodeName` and `aroundMethodName` which we are using for Override ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find everything to know in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#defining-a-plugin

> ### Before methods
>
> Before methods run prior to an observed method. These methods must
>   have the same name as the observed method with ‘before’ as the prefix.
>
> You can use before methods to change the arguments of an observed
>   method by returning a modified argument. If there are multiple
>   arguments, the method should return an array of those arguments.
>   Returning null will indicate that the arguments for the observed
>   method should not be modified.
>
> ### After methods
>
> After methods run following the completion of the observed method.
>   These methods must have the same name as the observed method with
>   ‘after’ as the prefix.
>
> These methods can be used to modify the results of an observed method
>   and are required to have a return value.
>
> ### Around methods
>
> Around methods are defined such that their code is run both before and
>   after the observed method. This allows you to completely override a
>   method. Around methods must have the same name as the observed method
>   with ‘around’ as the prefix.
>
> Before the list of the original method’s arguments, around methods
>   receive a callable that will allow a call to the next method in the
>   chain. When the callable is called, the next plugin or the observed
>   function is called.

On top of that, I suggest you read this great article from Alan Storm: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_plugin_system